# Events with multiple event dates + permalink for each date

Tags: custom-post-types, meta-query, events

Hope you're well. I was wondering how to achieve something like this in wp:

[image: Wordpress multiple event dates]

Bascally it's a list of events ordered by the event date. I know how to do that. But the tricky part is that an event may have multiple event dates like in the picture and EACH event date has a custom permalink and single page.

Something like a PARENT event and then CHILD event.

May someone help me?

Thanks a lot!

Jhon

Comment: Heirarchical custom post type? I can think of several ways to do this, all very different and all more of less useful depending on the details.

Comment: Well, thanks for the reply.

Every date as a description and a custom link to buy tickets outside the website.

That's it! 

My problem is to link children event dates to the main event and list them!